# How can I get the ADT Banner to show on start up instead of the eclipse banner?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I run eclipse with the ADT plug-in, the purple Eclipse loading banner appears instead of the black and green ADT loading banner.  I downloaded the ADT bundle for windows 7 64bit.  Am I missing the graphic or is there a way to adjust this in the settings?

I want this to show up on start-up:
[ADT Graphic http://www.limecreativelabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/adt-bundle2.jpg](http://www.limecreativelabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/adt-bundle2.jpg)

Instead of this:
[image: Eclipse Juno Graphic]

Comment: Whats the problem with the banner its just a tool. Main aim is to code. And get the job done. Don't waste ur time in these stupid things

Comment: I think they took the ADT banner out for some reason, maybe with switch to Android Studio.

Comment: @james Just curious as to how the program start-up works and how to change the banner of a program. I don't think that knowing about the tool and how it works is stupid.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that banner because you are running that bundled `IDE`. If you want that `eclipse JUNO` banner, then you should download `eclipse JUNO` itself without any bundled package. Then you may add the `ADT Plugin` and `SDK` manually.

Here are eclipse download link https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and ADT Plugin configuration link http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html.

Comment: I want the ADT banner, but I'm getting the eclipse Juno banner

Comment: ok, then go to eclipse folder. There you will see **icon.xpm**. You can manually add android studio logo and reference that one on start up.

Comment: where exactly is the icon.xpm located, I don't see it in the eclipse folder

Comment: what os you are using?